# How does this geometric application of proof by infinite descent work

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, infinite-descent

In the book "The Moment of Proof" by Donald C. Benson, Chapter 4 page 51, he gave a geometric application of infinite descent.

> proposition 4.7:
>
> Let $S$ be a finite set of points. Suppose that a straight line connecting any two points of $S$ always contains a third point of $S$. Then all of the points of $S$ lie in a straight line.

This is the proof he provided. I rephrased it a little:

*Proof.*
Suppose that the points in $S$ do not belong to the same straight line. Then at least one of the points in $S$, we call $P$, is at a positive distance from a line determined by two other points in S, $A \ 
 and\ B$. Let that positive distance be $d_0$ and the line $AB$ be $l_0$. Assume that there is a third point $C$ that belongs to $S$ that lies on $l_0$.

Define $Q$ to be a point on $l_0$ such that $PQ \perp l_0$ and $\bar{PQ} = d_0$. The right or left line emanating from Q must contain two of three points $A,B,C$. Let the line emanating from Q such that that line contains two of the three points be $h_1$. Out of that two points, one point is farthest from Q and one point is nearer to Q. Call it $F$ (far) and $N$ (near) respectively. $N$ lies on segment $QF$. Define $l_1$ to be line $PF$ and $d_1$ the be perpendicular distance from $N$ to $l_1$. Let point $R$ to be on a point $l_1$ such that $RN \perp l_1$ and $\bar{RN} = d_1$

Since $\triangle FRN \sim \triangle FQP$, and $FR<FP$, we can say that $RN<PQ$. Therefore, $d_1<d_0$. That means that $d_0$ isn't the shortest distance. $\blacksquare$

I have two questions regarding this proof.

1. We have taken $d_0$ to be the smallest distance and shown that $d_1<d_0$. But if we chose $d_1$ to be the smallest distance, there will not be any smaller distance, so how would the proof continue?
2. Even if we have shown that $d_0$ isn't the smallest distance, how does that prove or disprove the statement?

Thank you!

Edit: For question 1, I believe that the proof will continue if I add a new point in $S$ such that it is between $R$ and $F$. From there, we can use the same logic (have a line emanate out of $R$... so on and so forth). This shows that there is indeed no such thing as "shortest distance". But I still cannot figure out question 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are only finitely many points, some triple $A, B$ and $C$ must realize the minimum. By continuing to find triples with a smaller $d$ we must eventually arrive at this minimum triple or to a triple that we've already seen. Both lead to contradiction. In fact, we could assume that the $A, B, C$ we pick in the first place is the minimum. I mean, just pick it!

Comment: I'm still a little doubtful. If we pick the minimum, how do we generate the contradiction then when all the other $d$ are bigger than it. Also, I am not extremely certain how seeing a $d$ we have already seen leads to a contradiction. I would appreciate it if you could clarify that. Thank you.

Comment: @Chavez They find a $d_1$ that is strictly smaller than the $d_0$. That is the contradiction if $d_0$ is the minimum. And seeing a $d$ that is already seen is a contradiction because each step the $d$ is strictly smaller than the previous one, so we have $d_0 > d_1 > \dots > d_0$.

Comment: So proof by infinite descent wants us to find a smaller step of "d" through some sort of mathematical algorithm, so we have to find a smaller step of d. 

if we find a smaller d, it will contradict the statement that d is the smallest. 

if we have revisited another d, then it will break the inequality, causing a contradiction.

Comment: @Chavez: This answer is correct but not entirely satisfactory. Beyond what this answer says, you must know that this principle of picking the minimum from a finite set (called the "extremal principal") is **intrinsically** based on induction along ℕ (the naturals). In particular, the induction hypothesis Q(k) is that every set of k real numbers has a minimum, and induction yields that every finite set of real numbers has a minimum. It is crucial to know this, otherwise you cannot really understand exactly why and when the extremal principle works.